# Alternative to itertools.tee in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm doing some processing of large input data split over several files.  Trying to separate the processing algorithms from the I/O, I set everything up using generators.  This works pretty well except when I want to do some intermediate manipulations of the data passing through the generators.  Here's an example that hits the important points

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import izip, tee

# Have two input matrices.  In reality they're very large, so data is provided
# one row at a time via generators.
M, N = 100, 3
def gen_data_rows(m,n):
    for i in range(m):
        yield np.random.normal(size=n)

rows1 = gen_data_rows(M,N)
rows2 = gen_data_rows(M,N)

# Signal processing operates on chunks of the input, e.g. blocks of rows and
# yields results at a reduced rate.  Here's a simple example.
def foo_rows(rows):
    i = 0
    for row in rows:
        if i % 5 == 0:
            yield row
        i += 1

# But what if we want to do some transformations between the raw input data
# and the processing?
def fun1(x, y):
    return x + y

def fun2(x, y):
    return (x + y)**2

def foo_transformed_rows(rows1, rows2):
    # Define a generator that consumes both inputs at the same time and
    # produces two streams of output I'd like to send to foo_rows().
    def gen_transformed_rows(rows1, rows2):
        for x, y in izip(rows1, rows2):
            yield fun1(x,y), fun2(x,y)

    # Do I really need to tee the above and define separate generators to pick
    # off each result?
    def pick_generator_idx(gen, i):
        for vals in gen:
            yield vals[i]

    gen_xformed_rows, dupe = tee(gen_transformed_rows(rows1, rows2))
    gen_foo_fun1 = foo_rows(pick_generator_idx(gen_xformed_rows, 0))
    gen_foo_fun2 = foo_rows(pick_generator_idx(dupe, 1))
    for foo1, foo2 in izip(gen_foo_fun1, gen_foo_fun2):
        yield foo1, foo2


for foo1, foo2 in foo_transformed_rows(rows1, rows2):
    print foo1, foo2
```

I think the main complication here is that I've got two inputs that I want to combine into two intermediate generators (I/O is the bottleneck, so I really don't want to run through the data twice).  Is there a better way to implement the `foo_transformed_rows()` function?  Having to `tee()` the the desired data and define generators just to pick items out of a tuple seems like overkill.

**Edit**: I modified the example slightly in response to a comment, but unfortunately it's still pretty long in order to remain complete.  The essential problem is dealing with a multi-input-multi-output (MIMO) data stream.  I guess I'd like something like a `yield` statement that produces multiple generators, e.g.

```
def two_streams(gen_a, gen_b):
    "Consumes two generators, produces two results."
    for a, b in itertools.izip(gen_a, gen_b):
        c, d = foo(a, b)
        yield c, d

# This doesn't work.  You get one generator of tuples instead of
# two generators of singletons.
gen_c, gen_d = two_streams(gen_a, gen_b)
```

I thought maybe there would be some itertools magic to do the equivalent.

Comment: Can you reduce your example to an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Since you're iterating both outputs from `tee` in parallel, you're not really wasting much on overhead; `tee` is expensive (in terms of memory) if you're draining each result generator separately (because until the last `tee`-ed generator is drained, the values must be stored internally), but when draining in parallel, the cost is pretty minor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @ShadowRanger's comment, and I don't see why you want to avoid the `tee`. It works well for this purpose.

However, it seems simpler and more intuitive to me to tee the original generators:

```
def transform_rows(fun, rows1, rows2):
    for x, y in izip(rows1, rows2):
        yield fun(x,y)

rows1a, rows1b = tee(rows1)
rows2a, rows2b = tee(rows2)
gen_foo_fun1 = foo_rows(transform_rows(fun1, rows1a, rows2a)
gen_foo_fun2 = foo_rows(transform_rows(fun2, rows1b, rows2b)
```